# mysqli update query - call to function bind_param on non object

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update, prepared-statement

So I know what causes this error...but I'm having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my query.

The error is:  Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

```
function failedLogin($user){

  global $logins;
  $logins++;

  //My db connection
  global $db;
  if($db ->connect_error){
     echo mysqli_connect_error();
     exit();    
  }

    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `Users` SET `loginAttempts` = ? WHERE `username` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('is',$logins,$user);
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

my table structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbdNa.png

I know the connection is good because I've used to select data from my table when they login..just having trouble updating my table

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Error:  Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/includes/loginUtils.php on line 58

Comment: `prepare()` must be failing for some reason then.

Comment: Yes. I know. That's why I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with the query.

Comment: Is there anything else in your logs? Apache or mysql?

Comment: the problem is you have to pass as parameter the database conection, you dont have conection into that function

Comment: mysqli::prepare returns "FALSE if an error occurred". what does $db->error say?

Comment: `var_dump($db)` after `global $db` (you shouldn't really be doing globals anyways)

Comment: also -- `if($db->connect_error)` will not fire if $db is null/false/etc. `if(empty($db) || $db->connect_error)` would be better, if you're set on using global. @EmilioGort's answer is correct that you are better passing it as a parameter than using a global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you have to pass as parameter the database conection, you dont have conection into that function

```
function failedLogin($db,$user){
//Your $db is null in you code, and i recomended never make your db connection global
}
```

Comment: Okay. So I tried moving all my database connection stuff into this function to test and it seems to function correctly now. I'm a bit confused because this function is in an included file in my index.php script. So should I put my connection info in index.php and pass it when I call failedLogin?

Comment: Dont move your connection into your function, you have to do the connection one time and rehuse it in all your function, passing it as a parameter when you want to use in another function

Comment: What is the better way of doing that without a global variable then? As in how can I declare it once and use it everywhere?

Comment: an example in the way you are working, a file database.php that conatains your connection <?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database;charset=UTF-8', 
               'username','password'); other file index.php that constain require('database.php'); and you can use your function failedLogin($db,$user)